# A clickable image on top of an image

Tags: html, php, image

I have a page where we can see a number of image, in a gridview (like)

I want the user to be able to delete them ; I want to put a small X image on the top right corner of every image. What is the best way to do that?

I tried with Image Map but i cannot set a image, only a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to position it over the original image. Here's a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QPr5U/1/

I made a list of icons, where every image is in it's own `li` element. It could be divs or whatever, as long as every image is wrapped by another element, and a list is semantically the most correct.
Together with each image is a link with a width and height of 16px and a background image of a cross.

The trick is that the element around the image has a `position: relative`. This means that anything inside that `li` element that has a position, is relative to the boundaries of the `li`.
So if I now give the `.cross` element a `position: absolute` with a top and right value of 2px, this means the cross will be positioned 2px from the top and right of the list item.

The last thing I did was give the `li` items `display: inline-block` so that they don't span the entire width of the page, but only the width of the contents inside them. If you know how wide each image is going to be, you could also just give the `li` a fixed width.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

keep the individual images as the background image of any `div` and then set the cross image on that `div`

Comment: Semantically that wouldn't be correct, because the actual images are content and should be in an `img` tag. The cross however is layout, and should be set as a background to a link.